# "...превосходящие силы условного противника" — можно ли так писать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, сложное-предложение

Оригинал:

> Российские военные уничтожили превосходящие силы условного противника в ходе учений на полигоне Ляур в Таджикистане.

Как это понять  с точки зрения русского языка?

Comment: Это русский язык. Что имено вызывает затруднения в понимании?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь вполне допустимым образом соединены широко употребляемые военные термины "**превосходящие силы противника**" и "**условный противник**".

Понимать это нужно так, что в ходе учений некое подразделение (здесь условно "российские военные") вступило в учебный бой с другими подразделениями, превосходящими его по численности личного состава и/или количеству/качеству вооружений и условно их уничтожило (в игровом пейнтболе "уничтожение" оценивалось бы попаданием в человека пулей с краской; у военных могут быть другие средства и условности). Этот противник условен в том смысле, что формально не назван (как государство или известная террористическая группировка), но может трактоваться как один из *вероятных* противников, напр. упомянутых в военной доктрине или в документе, регламентирущем конкретные учения.

Comment: *(здесь условно "российские военные")* Да нет там ничего условного. >>>>>Мотострелковые и танковые подразделения 201-й военной базы России уничтожили превосходящие силы условного противника в рамках учений на полигоне Ляур в Таджикистане https://ruptly.tv/en/videos/20200614-056 Где-то даже было инфа, что в роли "противника" выступали подразделения охраны и обслуживания. Это, кстати обычная практика для зарубежных баз - чтобы не перебрасывать дополнительный контингент на время учений.

Answer (score 0):

Это язык военно-канцелярских журналистов, часто оторванных от гражданской реальности.
При том, однако, во фразе все более или менее правильно, кроме одного. "Условного противника" можно уничтожить только условно. Поэтому надо или кавычки использовать, или так и писать "условно уничтожен". К сожалению, с давних пор эти пренебрегают- в угоду, видимо, военному языку, где "условный противник" канонизирован, а "условное уничтожение" считается чем-то неправильным.

Никаких других новаций в этом обороте нет.

Comment: В многочисленных книжках, которые пишут военные, "условного" противника уничтожают даже "беспощадно", либо у них "условно уничтожают" военные объекты и подразделения, названные _реальными_ именами. Фразеология же "_условно_ уничтожить _условного_ противника" мне пока не встречалась.

Comment: Ну так и я о том, что УСТАВ уничтожил разум.

Comment: ЗЫ https://vesti92.ru/news/flot/raketnye-kompleksy-bal-bastion-i-utyos-unichtozhil/ Это, конечно, Крым, а они там с 2014 г. вообще чувство юмора потеряли, но таки "Условно уничтожить корабельную ударную группу условного противника"